# Array of Structs returning unusual data in Solidity

Tags: struct, solidity, smartcontracts

I am creating one Voting Smart Contract people can organize one election and voters can vote for their candidate. I have created one function which will return the statistics of ongoing or past elections

```
///@dev making statistics for all ballot/election
    ///@return results with all the information of all
    function getStatisticsOfAllVote()
        public
        view
        returns (SingleElectionStatistics[] memory )
    {

        SingleElectionStatistics[] memory results = new SingleElectionStatistics[](BallotArray.length);

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < BallotArray.length; i++) {
            SingleElectionStatistics memory temp = SingleElectionStatistics(
                BallotArray[i]._getName(), //CEO election 
                BallotArray[i]._getDescription(),//Employees will choose their CEO 
                BallotArray[i]._getTotalVoteCounted(),//BigNumber { value: "1" } 
                BallotArray[i]._isVotingEnded(),//true 
                BallotArray[i]._getWinningProposalName()//John 
            );
            results[i] = temp;
        }
        
        return results;
    }
```

Sample returns are added as comments after the function call.

I suppose to get one array of objects. Buts it gave me data unusual format with extra data. Here are the returns data:

```
[
  [
    'CEO election',
    'Employees will choose their CEO',
    BigNumber { value: "1" },
    true,
    'John',
    name: 'CEO election',
    description: 'Employees will choose their CEO',
    voteCounted: BigNumber { value: "1" },
    voteEnded: true,
    winningProposalName: 'John'
  ]
]
```

Which should return only

```
[
  {
    name: 'CEO election',
    description: 'Employees will choose their CEO',
    voteCounted: BigNumber { value: "1" },
    voteEnded: true,
    winningProposalName: 'John'
  }
]
```

I may need help from the community. Thanks in advance

I tried with unit tests and also by changing the approaches but it doesn't help at all.

Comment: Can you share your entire smart contract?

Answer (score 0):

The raw data returned from a node (using [eth_call](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_call) RPC method) is an ABI-encoded byte array, containing each item just once.

The duplication that you see is caused by an offchain framework. Based on other context, I'm assuming that you're using `ethers.js`.

Their [docs page](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/abi/interface/#Result) says:

> A **Result** is an array, so each value can be accessed as a positional argument.
>
> Additionally, if values are named, the identical object as its positional value can be accessed by its name.

In your case, the call returns an array of `Result` types. Since the Solidity return variables are named (your `ethers.js` instance knows this from the ABI JSON generated during Solidity compilation), each `Result` type contains both number-indexed and named items.